# Cannot properly parse JSON Data because of its format?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am trying to parse data which look:
[image]

It looks like each record is sequential.. 0, 1, 2 and then within each record there are lots of key value pairs such as the name or showID.

I want to go into each record and only get certain pairs, for example the name, showID and Date.

Here is my code, I am unsure what should be my modal in for item in loop

in other words, how do I get the specific fields into my empty dictionary array?

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data
        {
            do
            {
                var jsonResult:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as! NSArray?
                {
                    var emptyArrayOfDictionary = [[String : AnyObject]]()

                    for item in 0...jsonResult.count
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please add the first 10-15 characters of the JSON string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea would be to create a struct (or a class) which contains the properties you need, created with an initializer from the values in your dictionaries.

Let's say you want to make "Show" objects containing the show name and the show ID.

You could create a struct like this:

```
struct Show {
    let name:String
    let showID:Int
    init?(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
          let showID = dictionary["showID"] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
        self.showID = showID
    }
}
```

Then iterate over your dictionaries and pass each one to the struct initializer, something like this:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if let urlContent = data {
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject] {

                if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                    let shows = items.flatMap { Show(dictionary: $0) }

                }

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

The struct initializer is an Optional one, meaning that if the dictionary does not contain the keys "name" or "showID" it will not create the object and will return nil instead; that's why we're using `flatMap` to iterate instead of `map` (because flatMap unwraps the Optionals).

Now you have an array of objects, `shows`, and you can filter or sort its contents easily with Swift methods like `sort`, `filter`, etc.

Each object in the `shows` array is a `Show` object and has `name` and `showID` properties with the data of your dictionaries.

What `flatMap` does is create an *array* of `Show` objects by iterating (like a loop) over the initial array. On this line:

```
let shows = items.flatMap { Show(dictionary: $0) }
```

the `$0` represents the current array element. What it means is that for each element in the `items` array, we take it and create a new `Show` instance with it, and put the resulting array of objects in the constant `shows`.

There's also `map` which is often used, but here the init of our `Show` struct is an optional init, so it returns an Optional Show, and `flatMap` knows how to deal with this (it will safely unwrap the optional and ignore the nil ones) where `map` does not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to run the simulator successful but then it crashed shortly after with this message: 

Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10d73b8d8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10d73bd60).

the line in question was this one: 

var jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

any thoughts??

Comment: First thought: `var jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]` is *not* code from my answer... Second thought: what you described as a dictionary in your question looks like it's actually an array.

Comment: What do you mean by it is NOT code? How could that be? For the second part, are you suggesting that the JSON data is in an array format and not a dictionary? so on this line here : let shows = items.flatMap { Show(dictionary: $0) } should i substitue dictionary for array?

Comment: Arbab, I never said it wasn't code, I said it wasn't code *from my answer*. In your comment, you show a crashing line, but this line is from your attempt, not from mine (I didn't use force-unwrapping). Use **my** code to try fixing your problem. If it still doesn't work, we'll try and fix it together. // Yes, by all means, try to adapt my answer to your actual data format. :) Guessing from your question about this format was not guaranteed to succeed for me and apparently it didn't...

Comment: Hey, great so after making some tweaks I was able to get your code working. Eric you've been a great help I hope this next question doesn't bother you. 

can you explain what this line is doing?  let shows = items.flatMap { Show(dictionary: $0) }

I think it is creating a constant called shows which is an instantiation of the class Show that we created and it is mapping each item to with a key? 

Can you explain better? I am trying to see how many values the "shows" constant now holds but I don't have any way to print it...I tired doing Print (shows.name) but it wont recognize it as a member.

Comment: I've added an explanation about flatMap in my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Erik, I now understand what flatmap does, it is just creating an array out of all the show objects we made. Since the problem still persists, (trying to print the shows array) using print (shows)  or shows.count it doesn't do anything. is there a different appraoch to this?

Comment: You're welcome. Your problem is just that your data is not in the format we thought it was, but now you've understood how to do what you asked in your question. You just have now to debug a bit - like, comment out everything inside `if let jsonResult ...` and do a `print(jsonResult)`, if it doesn't execute then it means that it's not a dictionary but an array, try with `as? [[String : AnyObject]]` instead and see if it prints, then adapt the rest, etc. :) (and of course if you're stuck after that, me or someone else will be there to help).

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for being patient. I am still having trouble. However, I have more information.

I know that the JSON is in the following format:

It is an array contain 1088 items
Each item in the array is an object containing 48 items

I know that I am getting the data from my task method as I have been able to print the URLcontent to the log.

I think issue is in NSJSONSerialization.
I took the url content and cast it as an array as follow: if let jsonResult: NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray

now?

Comment: Update: After doing the line in my previous comment, I followed it up with : let dataArray = jsonResult[0] as! NSDictionary
                        print (dataArray["name"])

and I was able to successfuly print only the name value of the 0th element..Im excited!. now I need to figure out how to iterate over each element and get the name value

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to simplify your son parsing try this Open source https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

With this you access name field of item 0

```
let userName = json[0]["name"].string
```